# How to make xmlhttprequest periodically?

Tags: javascript

I want to loop an httprequest every 5 seconds.

Here is my code :

```
var xmlhttp2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url2 = "http:...";
xmlhttp2.onreadystatechange = function() {
 if (xmlhttp2.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp2.status == 200) {
    var response2 = xmlhttp2.responseText;
    var response2 = xmlhttp2.responseText;
    var json2  = JSON.parse(response2); 
    for (var i = 2; i < json2.length; i++){
        document.getElementById('table2').innerHTML += '<tr><td>' + json2[i].nm + '</td><td>' + json2[i].id + '</td><td id="uid_'+i+'">' + json2[i].stn + '</td></tr>';
 }

}
xmlhttp2.open("GET", url2, true);
xmlhttp2.send();
```

I tried to put this whole code in a function and called

```
setInterval(myFunction,5000);
```

This works. However the table is displaying several times.

I tried

```
setInterval("xmlhttp2.send();",5000);
```

and this doesn't work. The request is made only once.

Any advice ?

Thank you

Comment: The first method is appropriate. What do you want to do with the response of the ajax request? If the table is displaying several times; then that is the code you prolly need to change.

Comment: What is the code of `// fill a table`? sounds like that part isn't reentrant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear the table before populating it with the server response

**Answer**

```
var xmlhttp2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url2 = "http:...";
xmlhttp2.onreadystatechange = function() {
 if (xmlhttp2.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp2.status == 200) {
    var response2 = xmlhttp2.responseText;
    var response2 = xmlhttp2.responseText;
    var json2  = JSON.parse(response2);
    var table = document.getElementById('table2');
    table.innerHTML = '';
    for (var i = 2; i < json2.length; i++){
        table.innerHTML += '<tr><td>' + json2[i].nm + '</td><td>' + json2[i].id + '</td><td id="uid_'+i+'">' + json2[i].stn + '</td></tr>';
 }

}
xmlhttp2.open("GET", url2, true);
xmlhttp2.send();
```

Use `setInterval(myFunction,5000);` to make periodic request.

**Edited**

```
var xmlhttp2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url2 = "http:...";
    xmlhttp2.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (xmlhttp2.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp2.status == 200) {
        var response2 = xmlhttp2.responseText;
        var response2 = xmlhttp2.responseText;
        var json2  = JSON.parse(response2);
        var tableBody = document.getElementById('table2Body');
        tableBody.innerHTML = '';
        for (var i = 2; i < json2.length; i++){
            tableBody.innerHTML += '<tr><td>' + json2[i].nm + '</td><td>' + json2[i].id + '</td><td id="uid_'+i+'">' + json2[i].stn + '</td></tr>';
     }

    }
    xmlhttp2.open("GET", url2, true);
    xmlhttp2.send();
```

Comment: and how do you that ?

Comment: I would call the first update directly and then use `setTimeout` after a successful refresh. Without doing so your request will stack if the network becomes temporarily slow or whatever... (and then eventually spam both server & client)

Comment: I have a last question, how can I clear table from row2 and keep row1 ?because I had th in my table. I need to clear all td I guess

Comment: You can separate heading and body using <thead> and <tbody>. Now clear and populate only <tbody> instead of <table>

Comment: Use this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qpszvjhy/) as reference and create your table. And get `tableBody` for populating the ajax response :)